# How to force PDOStatement->fetchAll to return array of objects?

Tags: php, object, pdo

I am writing my own simply ORM using PDO. My question is if you can force `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` method to return array of objects of stdClass? For example:

```
$result = $q->fetch_all(/* some magic here */);
print_r($result);
```

Should print something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [NAME] => pear
            [COLOUR] => green
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [NAME] => watermelon
            [COLOUR] => pink
        )

)
```

Is this posible? NAME and COLOUR are of course names of columns. I read documentation but I didn't find anything interesting.

Comment: I don't think you read the documentation clearly enough: "PDO::FETCH_OBJ: returns an anonymous object with property names that correspond to the column names returned in your result set"

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use `$result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`

Comment: Oh my. I miss this in the documentation. I thought that this is only about the first level (arrays in my case). Thanks.

Comment: Nothing, but the PDO has several modes, even define a name of an object that is defined getters, see PDO:: FETCH_CLASS

Comment: It is a good practice when demonstrating a documented feature such as a flag for a function argument to add a link to the documentation page that mentions this flag or copy and paste the necessary bits for the docs itself.

Comment: PDO::FETCH_OBJ is documented in [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and not mentioned in [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) which probably adds to the confusion.

Comment: In my experience with `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` fetchAll returns array of objects in php 5.6 and array of arrays in php 5.4. This also contributes to confusion. Are there php.ini settings that can modify it?

Answer (score 12):

This will do it:

```
 <?php
 $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
 $sth->execute();

 $result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 //$result contains an array of stdObjects
 ?>
```

However even cooler way is to get PDO to instantiate your own class and populate the properties for you:

> **Example #4 Instantiating a class for each result**
>
> The following example demonstrates the behaviour of the
>   PDO::FETCH_CLASS fetch style.

```
 <?php
 class fruit {
     public $name;
     public $colour;
 }

 $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
 $sth->execute();

 $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "fruit");
 //$result contains an array of fruit objects
 ?>
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to do the following:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //set the mode for all fetch request
```

With any subsequent `fetch` request you can omit explicitly specifying the mode.

```
$stmt->setFetchAll(); //returns an array of objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Set default mode to object using PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE by adding it to the connection options array,

```
 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, 
                 [PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ]
 );
```

Then no magic is needed, you can get expected result from:

```
$result = $q->fetchAll();
```